# How to get values of html textbox that is create dynamically inside a literal asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, literals

I would like to seek help in my project. I have created a dynamic table in a literal control in asp.net
Inside the literal table is a `<input type='text'>`

I am having a hard time retrieving the values of the `<input type='text'>`.

This is my code:

```
 strsql = "Select SaricasaNew.category from SaricasaNew where trans_id = " & fill
    PopulateGrid(strsql, gr1)

    For i = 0 To gr1.Rows.Count - 1
        display = display & "<table class = 'displayresult'><tr><th>" & gr1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text & "</th></tr>"

        strsql = "SELECT  SaricasaNew.value FROM dbo.SaricasaNew where SaricasaNew.category = '" & gr1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text & "' AND SaricasaNew.trans_id = " & fill
        PopulateGrid(strsql, gr2)

        For k = 0 To gr2.Rows.Count - 1
            display = display & "<tr><td><input id = 'Text1' class='bootstrap-tagsinput form-control' style='background: transparent;' data-role='tagsinput' type='text' value='" & gr2.Rows(k).Cells(0).Text & "' /></td></tr>"
        Next
    Next
    display = display & "</table>"

    Literal1.Text = display
```

This is the result:
[image]

I would really appreciate if someone helps me with this. Thank you so much!